# Create table at runtime with Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

According to this issue – [Dynamic Models in Phoenix Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853270/dynamic-models-in-phoenix-framework) – it is possible to dynamically create a model in Elixir using `Module.create`.

Is it also possible to create a table in the database for this model during runtime, i.e. without using Ecto migration files?

Comment: Just a quick question - what is the purpose of the table?

Comment: Every month I want to have a custom table to store data of a report. But I want the system to create this table when the user request the report (if it not exists).

Comment: What is the DB behind `Ecto`?

Comment: @mudasobwa MySQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PostgreSQL` and `MySQL` adapters for `Ecto` 2.0+ have an ability to execute raw SQL:

```
qry =
  """
  CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
  """

res = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(Repo, qry, [])
```

[`Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#query/4).

Another (might be preferred) way would be to just delegate this to underlying `mysql` shell executable:

```
System.cmd("mysql", ["#{create_table_script}"])
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it!

Comment: new link for Ecto 3+: [`Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#query!/4) The function was moved from the ecto package to the ecto_sql package

Comment: Note that `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query/4` is also available under your repositories, e.g. `MyRepo.query/4`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case (creating new report table every month) I would ditch creating DB table idea and consider using ETS / DETS combo. They are key-value stores (ETS - in-memory, DETS - data saved on disk - this is what you basically need) and you can read more about them [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/ets-tables-in-elixir--cms-29526).

Comment: And then comes audit and fires you out of the business for not keeping a backup of the reports. How this question answers “how to create a table in the MySQL database dynamically with Ecto”?

Comment: Who said anything about audit? How saving a report into DETS (and exporting it to whatever format you want if needed) is not a backup? Is there any difference between storing a data in key-value file and DB table (which is in fact another file on a disk)?
Dynamic tables can be fishy to handle and I have offered elegant alternative solution which is in line with Elixir / Erlang way of programming - this is how it answers the question.

Comment: Nobody uses DETS for long-term persistence. If you want to stay within OTP, use `mnesia` as a kv-store. Even “use `mnesia`” cannot be treated as a valid answer to “how to use `Ecto`,” though.

Comment: True, mnesia is another interesting solution but it's built on top of ETS/DETS anyway. I can of course add code examples if that will make my answer more answerish ;)

Comment: DETS are not distributed. `mnesia` is not “another interesting solution,” `mnesia` is the only way to go for long-term storage besides RDBMS.

Comment: Again, who said anything about distributed solution?

Comment: Let me sum up: you suggested to completely change the way of doing things to use DETS, that are not guaranteed to survive crashes and are working only within the same VM. You did not provide neither a code sample, nor a single argument why it makes any sense (hint: is does not.)

Comment: 1. I can provide a code sample as soon as I will receive more details about the use case.
2. Are you implying that DETS data are tend to be automagically and unpredictably disappearing? What “crashes” are going to cause that? 
3. So what they are available only within the same VM? Is this a condition mentioned anywhere in OP’s question? 
4. Why are you ignoring my questions, arguments and taking it so personal?
5. I disagree with your statement - in my opinion both, Mnesia and DETS are VALID tools for achieving OPs goal.

Comment: Your answer and your comments imply that you're treating this question as an ['XY problem'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) when the question as-is is perfectly valid and answerable. You're not *wrong* to do that, but this *answer* isn't the place to do that. And, regardless of OP's 'actual' problem, it's still a perfectly valid question for others to have.