# Wrap Postgres into a dedicated Phoenix App

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

**Goal**: Have a phoenix app (#1), that has empty (no tables) Postgres and on first boot waits to be further setup. Once it receives migration and model/schema files via http from other phoenix app (#2), it runs migrations, starts a `supervisor(App1.Repo, []),` and all received models/schemas from app #2 puts in state in `worker(App1.Models, [])`, so that app #1 can process queries like `Repo.all(User)`. Then, app #1 listens for requests from the app #2 and performs changes in Postgres.

**Reason**: Idea is to isolate DB completely from app #2, so that when it needs something from db, it just sends `Ecto` queries to app #1, and app #1 is able to perform that query and return a result. However, app #1 copy can be spawned for different apps, i.e. app #2, #3, #4, which all have different models/schemas, and on first connection provide their db settings (models/migrations) to app #1, which prepares its Postgres with those settings, and then just accept db queries.

---

### Example:

**Step 1**: App #1 receives `User` model and respective migration file from app #2.

**Step 2**: App #1 runs migration file to prepare Postgres.

**Step 3**: App #1 starts a GenServer (process?) with Ecto, Repo and newly received `User` model from app #2 and listens for incoming requests.

**Step 4**: App #1 receives request, runs query, and returns list of all users in its db.

```
%{
  query: 'User',
  command: 'all'
 } 
 # Should run by app #1 as Repo.all(User)
```

---

### Problems:

1. First of all, is it even possible to do something like this? Or there is some fundamental issue in the idea?
2. How can app #1 run migrations received dynamically, without start/stopping its server? Can we place migrations files (received from app #2) in some directory and then run something like `Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Migrate.run()` to run all migrations?
3. **Solved** Can App #1 compile models/schemas (received from app #2), start a GenServer with those models and make them available to run commands, like `Repo.all(User)`? Or can we use received models/schemas to dynamically create [modules](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html), and pass those modules to `App1.Repo`, in order to perform queries like `Repo.all(User)`, where `User` is a dynamically generated module? **Solution:** Using logic from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853270/dynamic-models-in-phoenix-framework), I was able to dynamically create modules, and then use them to perform queries.

I might have confused some things, but I believe solving these problems will help achieve the goal...? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Although I could hardly imagine a benefit of this architecture this is surely possible.
2. Sure, why not?

Use [`Ecto.Migrator`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migrator.html#content):

```rb
def migrate! do
  path = Application.app_dir(:my_app, "priv/repo/migrations")
  Ecto.Migrator.run(MaApp.Repo, path, :up, all: true)
end
```

3. I would take an advantage of using ErlangVM, running the remote functions on different nodes with [`Node.spawn/*`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Node.html#spawn/2) instead of re-inventing a wheel.

That way one might use the the code from `App2` from `App1` to deal with models/schemas. Maybe I misunderstood the goal here, though, but since it’s already marked a solved, I would live my comment as an additional suggestion.

Comment: Thanks man, Ecto.Migrator is what I was looking for. And the reason for such architecture is to decouple database from app. So then we can build more powerful logic in app #1, such as caching, sync with other db, and generally have full control, before data is persisted.